# Is there any TDL code to check internet active status in tally prime?

Tags: tdl

I want to find the internet active status inside tally using TDL code. Can anyone help me out to find the active status of internet of the system.

I found a function called $$IsInternetActive from the tally developer editor but that returns logical "Yes" in both the instances (When internet is connected it returns "Yes" and when internet is not available also it returns "Yes").